# The problem that a value whose index I know with the loc function cannot update another column in the same index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Datatable:

```
         ARAÇ      VEHICLE_YEAR   NUM_PASSENGERS
0        CHEVROLET      2017           NaN
1        NISSAN         2017           NaN
2        HYUNDAI        2017           1.0
3        DODGE          2017           NaN
```

I want to update more than one index and column data on that index with the loc function.
but when I use the loc function, it changes the new values ​​by twos

```
listcolumns = ['VEHICLE_YEAR', 'NUM_PASSENGERS']
listnewvalue = [16000, 28000]
indexlister = [0, 1]

data.loc[indexlister , listcolumns] = listnewvalue
```

As you can see in the output below. just zero and the first index 'VEHICLE_YEAR' should be 16000, 'NUM_PASSENGERS' should be 28000. BUT, BOTH ZERO AND THE FIRST ROW HAS CHANGED IN BOTH COLUMNS.
How can i check this and change only the columns and index i want.or do you have a different method? thank you very much.

output:

```
     ARAÇ      VEHICLE_YEAR   NUM_PASSENGERS
0  CHEVROLET     16000         28000.0
1  NISSAN        16000         28000.0
```

In the printout, I set  fields to be empty so that new entries appear.  for example; I want to assign the value 2005 to the 0 index of the column 'VEHICLE_YEAR' and to the 1st index 2005 of the column 'NUM_PASSENGERS'

The output I want is as follows:

```
             ARAÇ     VEHICLE_YEAR  NUM_PASSENGERS
0        CHEVROLET         2005             Nan
1           NISSAN          Nan             2005
2           HYUNDAI         Nan             Nan
```

Comment: What did your table look like before you called loc() and what are you expecting it to look like after?

Comment: I added my table. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list you're setting the values with needs to correspond to the number of rows and number of columns you've selected with loc. If it receives a single list, it will assign all selected rows at those columns to that value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ARAC' : ['CHEVROLET', 'NISSAN', 'HYUNDAI', 'DODGE'],
    'VEHICLE_YEAR' : [2017, 2017, 2017, 2017],
    'NUM_PASSENGERS' : [np.nan, np.nan, 1.0, np.nan]
})

        ARAC  NUM_PASSENGERS  VEHICLE_YEAR
0  CHEVROLET             NaN          2017
1     NISSAN             NaN          2017
2    HYUNDAI             1.0          2017
3      DODGE             NaN          2017

df.loc[[0, 2], ['NUM_PASSENGERS', 'VEHICLE_YEAR']] = [[1000, 2014], [3000, 2015]]

        ARAC  NUM_PASSENGERS  VEHICLE_YEAR
0  CHEVROLET          1000.0          2014
1     NISSAN             NaN          2017
2    HYUNDAI          3000.0          2015
3      DODGE             NaN          2017
```

If you only want to change the values in the NUM_PASSENGERS column, select only that and give it a single list/array, the same length as your row indices.

```
df.loc[[0,1,3], ['NUM_PASSENGERS']] = [10, 20, 30]
        ARAC  NUM_PASSENGERS  VEHICLE_YEAR
0  CHEVROLET            10.0          2014
1     NISSAN            20.0          2017
2    HYUNDAI          3000.0          2015
3      DODGE            30.0          2017
```

The docs might be helpful too. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc

If this didn't answer your question, please provide your expected output.

Comment: I added the new description and what I want to get. thank you

Comment: To set specific values in different rows of different columns, I believe you'll need to call loc for each column. df.loc[[0], 'VEHICLE_YEAR'] = 2015 df.loc[[1], 'NUM_PASSENGERS'] = 2015

Comment: I don't want to tire you, thank you very much, but I get the data of this from the user and once I have to run all the data in a for loop. but when it enters the for loop, it gives the output that I unfortunately encountered.

Comment: thank you so much. You took time for me. You gave me different points of view. Of course, I wasn't expecting a ready-made solution directly. But you have come up with a complete solution. It doesn't matter if it literally solved my problem. it mobilized the piles of thoughts in my head and I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows.
I could not describe the problem exactly, I am working on it, but when I changed it that way, it worked. And now I can change the row and column value I want to the value I want.

```
listcolumns = ['VEHICLE_YEAR', 'NUM_PASSENGERS']
listnewvalue = [16000, 28000]
indexlister = [0, 1]

for i in len(indexlister):
    df.loc[lister[count], listcolumn[count]] = listnewvalue[count]
```